# How to change view folder location?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using .Net MVC 4, and have built a theme engine which changes the search for view from `~/views/` to `~/themes/foo/views`. This all works fine, but Visual Studio environment does not know the folder exists, so I get context errors.

How does the environment know what folder the views are in? And how do I edit/change that?

Update: The intellisense in Visual Studio does not provide the correct context based menu, when the view folder is moved.  How do I tell Visual Studio where the view folder exists?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass WebFormViewLocator and add your custom path to the list of paths.

Check [this article](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2008/07/31/37827/) on how to implement this.

Comment: Hi, I had this part working already, the issue is the Visual Studio Environment does not know the themes folder contains views.  Right click on the ~/Views folder and you get context aware menus.  How do I tell Visual Studio that a folder is a View folder?